# Is there any http automation tool / library that performs http requests directly instead of automating a browser?

Tags: http, automation

I'm looking for a tool / library (preferably .NET based) that does web page record/playback. I want this tool to issue http requests directly instead of automating a browser for performance reasons. Come to think of it, I'm pretty much looking for a recorder that can generate code that uses the WebClient class in .NET.

All of the tool I've found are designed for web-based UI testing so they interface with browsers in order to support javascript, dialogs, etc.

Comment: google "load testing" or "stress testing"

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this interests you, but I use a combination of fiddler & curl, and sometimes Wireshark:

Fiddler: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/
Curl: http://curl.haxx.se/
Wireshark: http://www.wireshark.org/

There is no recording/replaying of scripts, but I find these two tools very useful,

Fiddler for looking at the requests & responses, Curl for replaying them and wireshark for when it gets really messy.

Comment: Fiddler can actually replay requests.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I did know that.

Answer (score 1):

The LoadRunner virtual user generator (VUGen) works by recording and playing back the HTTP requests. You can download a trial of LoadRunner from HP and just intall VUGen if you want to play around with it. It generates scripts in a proprietary flavor of C, but it may give you some ideas of how to do the same thing in .NET.

There's also an open source load testing tool called[WebLoad](http://www.webload.org/), that I believe was created by the original developers of LoadRunner. My guess is that they have a scripting component that works similar to VUGen. You can find the [source code for WebLoad](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=189476) on SourceForge.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with a tool that will do what you're looking for that's .Net based, but if you can tolerate a Java UI, [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) will do exactly what you're looking for.

It's basically a load-testing tool that functions at the transport (ie, Request/Response) level. It has record/playback/scripting functionality and supports a number of different protocols.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [NUnitASP](http://nunitasp.sourceforge.net/) to verify that the page loads and doesn't throw an exception, but it doesn't really do very much UI interaction; and no javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I've used HttpUnit in Java quite a bit.  A quick google search finds [this page](http://xprog.blogspot.com/2004/07/web-page-unit-tests.html) with a few HttpUnit clone projects, so that might be a place to start.

I've tried to use Java HttpUnit tests with .NET apps before, but .NET's usage of postbacks and viewstate makes it pretty ugly (if it works at all).